# Send Mail with Outlook 365

Tags: c#, smtp, office365

I am trying to send emails through Outlook 365. I get the following error.
SMTP Error: [MustIssueStartTlsFirst]
Message: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.

My code:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailInfo.FromAddr, mailInfo.Password);
    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(mailInfo.Server) {
        Port = mailInfo.Port,
        EnableSsl = true, //mailInfo.SSL,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = cred,
        TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com"
    };


MailMessage message = new MailMessage {
    From = new MailAddress(mailInfo.FromAddr, mailInfo.FromName),
    Subject = "Manifest Processor Shipment Report - Manifest: " + shipment.ManifestNumber,
    Body = BuildManifestEmailBody(shipment),
    Priority = MailPriority.High,
    IsBodyHtml = true
};
```

What is strange, is I have a small test program that runs, using the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Outlook Mail REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) in MSDN. The Outlook Mail API lets you read, create, and send messages and attachments, view and respond to event messages, and manage folders in a user's mailbox in Office 365 or Exchange Online.

Also you may find EWS helpful. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.